# If I have a UK residence card, can I move to Italy?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa, italy

If I have a UK residence card, as it has almost no requirments for me to obtain, with my husband being Italian, can we move to Italy permanently?

Comment: Have you been living with your Italian citizen husband in the UK? If so, for how long? If you want to join your EU spouse in their country of origin and you haven't lived together in another EU country before, only national rules will apply to your situation.

Comment: @Traveller Italy has passed a law that guarantees that its national rules are at least as favorable as those specified in the free movement directive, so it doesn't matter where they've lived or for how long.

Comment: @phoog Noted. The source for my comment was https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/family-residence-rights/non-eu-wife-husband-children/index_en.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you move to Italy, you must apply for a residence permit based on Italian residence laws.

Your residence status in another European Union country is, in most cases, **irrelevant**.

As a Spouse of a EU-Citizen, most (but not all) EU Countrys, have special conditions for granting residence permits. Some EU countries implement extra national laws when the EU-Citizen is a citizen of their country. These laws can be more restrictive in nature.

As an Italian citizen, he is, no doubt, registered in the **[Italiani Residenti Estero](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html)** (AIRE) system.

This would be the proper place to inform oneself **properly** about what must be done and possibly start any needed procedure.